# Why isn't the "booklet" package behaving as expected?

Tags: book-design

I'm trying to use the `booklet` package to typeset a gathering of folios. Without the `booklet` package, the document would be typeset on 5.5 × 8.5 portrait pages. It's my understanding that `booklet` can be coaxed into placing pairs of these 5.5 × 8.5 pages side by side on 11 × 8.5 landscape pages, in the correct order for binding.

I'm having lots of problems, but I'll start with the most basic one: **I can't even get `booklet` to output 11 × 8.5 pages.**

Below is a stripped-down sample of my document. When the `booklet` package is removed (or passed the `noprint`) option, pdfLaTeX correctly outputs four 5.5 × 8.5 portrait pages:

```
 -------   -------   -------   ------- 
|       | |       | | Sam   | | SAM   |
| Frodo | | FRODO | |       | |       |
|       | |       | | Merry | | MERRY |
 -------   -------   -------   -------
```

When the `booklet` package is enabled, I expect to get two 11 × 8.5 landscape pages, something like this:

```
 --------------   -------------- 
| SAM          | |        Sam   |
|        Frodo | | FRODO        |
| MERRY        | |        Merry |
 --------------   --------------
```

Instead, I get four 5.5 × 8.5 portrait pages:

```
 -------   -------   -------   ------- 
| SAM   | |       | |       | |       |
|       | | FRODO | |       | |       |
| MERRY | |       | |       | |       |
 -------   -------   -------   -------
```

What's going on?

### Sample Code

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{color}

% page layout
\setlength{\paperwidth}{5.5in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{8.5in}
\usepackage[nohead,left=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.25in]{geometry}

% paragraph and box options
\setlength{\parindent}{0in}
\setlength{\parskip}{0in}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0in}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0in}

% printing
\usepackage[print,four]{booklet}
\source{\magstep0}{5.5in}{8.5in}
\target{\magstep0}{11in}{8.5in}
\setdvipstargetpages

\newcommand{\monopage}[2]{
\colorbox{magenta}{\begin{minipage}[c][7.5in]{\textwidth}
\setlength{\parskip}{16pt}
#1
\end{minipage}}
\colorbox{red}{\begin{minipage}[c][7.5in]{\textwidth}
\centering
#2
\end{minipage}}
}

\newcommand{\duopage}[4]{
\colorbox{cyan}{\begin{minipage}[c][3.75in]{\textwidth}
\setlength{\parskip}{16pt}
#1
\end{minipage}}
\colorbox{yellow}{\par\nopagebreak\begin{minipage}[c][3.75in]{\textwidth}
\setlength{\parskip}{16pt}
#3
\end{minipage}}
\colorbox{blue}{\begin{minipage}[c][3.75in]{\textwidth}
\centering
#2
\end{minipage}}
\colorbox{green}{\par\nopagebreak\begin{minipage}[c][3.75in]{\textwidth}
\centering
#4
\end{minipage}}
}

\begin{document}
% set font
\fontsize{24pt}{30pt}
\selectfont
\monopage{
Frodo
}{
FRODO
}
\duopage{
Sam
}{
SAM
}{
Merry
}{
MERRY
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `\setdvipstargetpages` behind `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Sorry I never checked back for your answer... a little after posting the question, I decided to change the way I was organizing my pages, and the issue I'd asked about became irrelevant. This is good to know, though!