# Can't get simple 4-page booklet printing to behave

Tags: booklet

Getting `booklet` printing working is proving more difficult than expected, even for just 4 pages. I have successfully used `geometry` to define an unusual paper size: A4 portrait halved from top to bottom. Then I add the `booklet` commands, and it combines pages 4 and 1 as expected onto a single A4 portrait page. But then page 2 is produced on its own, and then two blank pages. Page 3 is missing.

The same happens when I try A4 pages being reduced to A5 for a landscape booklet, so I don't think it's a result of my odd paper size.  I've followed advice in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24265/why-isnt-the-booklet-package-behaving-as-expected) and put `\setpdftargetpages` after the preamble.

(I know about `multicol` and the like, but as far as I cant tell that can't generate two-sided printing of sheets that can just be folded into booklets.)

MNWE:

```
\documentclass[14pt,onecolumn]{memoir}
\title{Booklet printing test}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\marginparsep = 0pt
\marginparwidth = 0pt
\headsep = 0pt
\footskip = 0pt
\usepackage[showframe,paperwidth=10.5cm,paperheight=29.7cm,includeheadfoot,includemp,textwidth=9.5cm,textheight=27cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[print,four,twouparticle]{booklet}
\source{\magstep0}{\paperwidth}{\paperheight}
\target{\magstep0}{21cm}{\paperheight} 

\begin{document}

\ifpdf
  \pdfoutput = 1
  \setpdftargetpages
\else
  \setdvipstargetpages
\fi

\maketitle

\subsection{One}
\lipsum[2]

\newpage
\subsection{Two}
\lipsum[4-5]

\newpage
\subsection{Three}
\lipsum[6-7]

\newpage
\subsection{Four}
\lipsum[8]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154810/39222) which I wrote in response to another question. `booklet` is essentially incompatible with `geometry`. The documentation explains how to resolve the issue but it has never worked for me. One workaround used `geometry` in the initial stage and then `booklet` only. That no longer works for me so I developed a solution independent of `booklet` which I explain in that answer, along with the failed, earlier solution. I do not currently know of a better answer though I am sure there must be one!

Comment: For booklets, I compile the main file as `a5paper`, then assemble the pages thus produced in an a4 document, with `pdfpages` and the `\includepdf` command.

Comment: I suggest Bernard's method with a modification. Use pdfbook (from pdfjam suite) to create the signatures for the booklet. It is much easier.

Comment: @masmys How is that easier than using the relevant option of `pdfpages`? `pdfjam` just wraps `pdfpages` anyway, I believe. Bernard's comment is essentially the basis of the answer I linked to in mine: compile the document to whatever size you like (A5 portrait in my case) and then use `pdfpages` in a wrapper `tex` document to create the signatures and prepare for printing onto whatever paper size (A4 landscape in my case). For example `\includepdf[pages=-,nup=1x2,landscape,signature=4]{firststagepdf}` for a 4 page signature.

Comment: I meant easier in the sense that one need not create a tex file and use \includepdf etc. to include the file, and then compile. Maybe, I should have said simpler than easier :-)

Comment: @cfr, I'd noted the warning in the documentation about `geometry` (namely "If you are making any changes to the values of `\paperwidth` or `\paperheight`, say through the geometry package or the memoir class, then the booklet package must be called after those changes have been made. In this case you may have to specify a different `\source` than usual, but I think that this is probably unlikely.") and put the `booklet` commands after `geometry`. But thank you for confirming that you have issues too.

Comment: I was really hoping to have a solution that required a single-pass of LaTeX. I generally write in markdown and then use pandoc to produce PDF output via LaTeX, supplying appropriate style and preamble commands. The `pdfpages` approach looks suitable, but would require a change in my workflow which I'd prefer to avoid. So, further answers still welcome!

Comment: @JGC Yes. I would have preferred that, too, which is why I consider my answer to the other question more of an alternative/work around than a true solution. (It eliminates `booklet` rather than fixing the issues.) However, after struggling for hours with it, I finally decided a change to my workflow was much less hassle. I really hope you get an answer which avoids this since I can then adopt it and go back to a single source file. (I think hoping for a single pass of LaTeX may be unrealistic but that does depend on content. I tend to have cross references and citations which rule that out.)

Comment: @cfr, indeed. I have asked the maintainer for help, but as the last update was 4 years ago, I'm not holding my breath.